# How to compile C++ Projects from Command Line

Tags: visual-c++

I have to compile a Visual C++ solution from command line. I can't do it with devenv.exe but can install .Net Framework SDK. Can I use the solution and project files to compile from the command line? If so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the .net framework SDK comes with msbuild, then just invoke:

```
msbuild mysolution.sln
```

That will cause a msbuild project to be generated from the solution, and the msbuild project will in turn instigate a call-out to vcbuild.  All solution level and project level dependencies will then be resolved and built in-order as needed.